# Use @variable in COLUMN name in SQL SERVER 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server, loops

Here, I've used SUM function on TRx1 column. 
I've TRx2,3,4,..53 Columns in the table.
I want to display all the columns using loop.

```
DECLARE @flag INT;
SET @flag = 1;

WHILE @flag <= 2
BEGIN

     select TOP 5 sd.OutletBPID, md.Product, SUM(TRx1)
     from sdata as sd, md, oa
     where sd.PSetID = md.PsetID
     group by sd.OutletBPID, md.Product;

SET @flag = @flag + 1;
END;
```

The following code i did but it shows error: "Invalid Column Name"

```
DECLARE @flag INT;
SET @flag = 1;

WHILE @flag <= 2
BEGIN

     select TOP 5 sd.OutletBPID, md.Product, SUM(TRx@flag)
     from sdata as sd, md, oa
     where sd.PSetID = md.PsetID
     group by sd.OutletBPID, md.Product;

SET @flag = @flag + 1;
END;
```

Comment: Any reason for the `plsql` tag?

Comment: @WilliamRobertson Loop comes under plsql tag right?

Comment: Not really. Click the tag for a definition.

Comment: @WilliamRobertson TAG REMOVED.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need dynamic sql

```
DECLARE @flag INT,
        @sql varchar(8000)=''
SET @flag = 1;


WHILE @flag <= 2
BEGIN

SET @sql = 'select TOP 5 sd.OutletBPID, md.Product, SUM(TRx'+cast(@flag as varchar(20))+')
            from sdata as sd, md, oa
            where sd.PSetID = md.PsetID
            group by sd.OutletBPID, md.Product'

    exec (@sql)

SET @flag = @flag + 1;
END;
```

Comment: Thanks, It works.
exec ('select TOP 5 sd.OutletBPID, md.Product, SUM(TRx'+@flag+') as TotalTRx'+@flag+'
     from sdata as sd, md, oa
     where sd.PSetID = md.PsetID
     group by sd.OutletBPID, md.Product')

Comment: Can't perform a CAST() inside EXEC() like that.

Comment: @AaronBertrand - yeah missed it. Updated my answer